# Erro ao instalar composer e laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer, wamp

Desinstalei e reinstalei uma versão mais recente do Vertrigo Server para ter o PHP 7, mas quando tento fazer algo com o Laravel ou o Composer na CMD aparece uma mensagem dizendo: "o programa não pode ser iniciado porque está faltando php5ts.dll no seu computador". Parece que ele não reconhece a nova versão do PHP, alguém sabe dizer o que pode ser isso?

Comment: Talvez a variável de ambiente ainda esteja apontando para a versão antiga do PHP, dê uma olhada nisso.

Answer (score 1):

Não é isso.

O que está acontecendo que provavelmente a extensão dessa DLL está desabilitada, para desencargo de consciência tente olhar no seu php.ini se todas as extensões necessárias estão habilitadas e aproveita e dá uma olhada nas suas configurações do apache.

Isso não é problema do laravel e sim de libs desabilitadas na instalação do seu PHP.